# Filtering results for twitch API once you make an API call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitch

I'm trying to build viewer that pulls from the twitch API to show which channels are online / offline.
I have 3 buttons: All (displays online and offline results), Online(displays only online results), and Offline (you guessed it...displays only offline results).

My code to display all results is as follows:`

```
var getAll = function () {

  $(".twitch-viewer-information").empty()          
  twitchUsernames.forEach(function (elem) {
    $.when($.getJSON(twitchApi + elem + apiCallback), $.getJSON(twitchStreamApi + elem + apiCallback)).done(function(data1,data2) {
      var twitchChannel = elem;
      var twitchLogo = data1[0].logo ? data1[0].logo : "https://www.skillsilo.com/images/profile-photo-default-256.png";
      var twitchStatus = checkStatus(data2);
      var twitchUrl = data1[0].url;
      var twitchStreamMessage = data2[0].stream ? data2[0].stream.channel.status.substring(0,33)+"..." : "";
      tableRow =$( 
        '<tr class="twitch-viewer-channel-data" data-href="'+ twitchUrl +'">' +
          '<td class="channel-pic"> <img class="channel-image" src="' + twitchLogo + '"</td>' +
          '<td class="twitch-viewer-channel-name">' + twitchChannel +  '<br> <span class="twitch-stream-message">' + twitchStreamMessage +'</span></td>' +
          '<td class="twitch-viewer-channel-status">' + twitchStatus + '</td>' +
        '<tr>'
        );
      $(".twitch-viewer-information").append(tableRow);
      tableRow.click(function() {
          window.location.href = $(this).data("href");
      });
    });
  });   
}
```

I'd like to now build a function that only returns the channels that are online, using as little code as possible. I have been rewriting the entire function, along with an if statement at the end to accomplish this...but there has got to be a simpler way:

```
var getOnline = function () {

  $(".twitch-viewer-information").empty()          
  twitchUsernames.forEach(function (elem) {
    $.when($.getJSON(twitchApi + elem + apiCallback), $.getJSON(twitchStreamApi + elem + apiCallback)).done(function(data1,data2) {
      var twitchChannel = elem;
      var twitchLogo = data1[0].logo ? data1[0].logo : "https://www.skillsilo.com/images/profile-photo-default-256.png";
      var twitchStatus = checkStatus(data2);
      var twitchUrl = data1[0].url;
      var twitchStreamMessage = data2[0].stream ? data2[0].stream.channel.status.substring(0,33)+"..." : "";
      tableRow =$( 
        '<tr class="twitch-viewer-channel-data" data-href="'+ twitchUrl +'">' +
          '<td class="channel-pic"> <img class="channel-image" src="' + twitchLogo + '"</td>' +
          '<td class="twitch-viewer-channel-name">' + twitchChannel +  '<br> <span class="twitch-stream-message">' +twitchStreamMessage +'</span></td>' +
          '<td class="twitch-viewer-channel-status">' + twitchStatus + '</td>' +
        '<tr>'
        );
      if(twitchStatus === "Online") {
          $(".twitch-viewer-information").append(tableRow);
        tableRow.click(function() {
            window.location.href = $(this).data("href");
          });
      }
    });
  });   
}
```

What is the shortest amount of code that I can user to duplicate my getAll function, while allowing me to filter for just the twitchStatus's that are online?